# How do I force pydantic schema into recursion instead of reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema, pydantic

According to [Pydantic's documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/),

> "Sub-models" with modifications (via the Field class) like a custom
> title, description or default value, are recursively included instead
> of referenced.

However, if I execute this code;

```
def test_me():

    class cls1(BaseModel):

        one: str
        two: str = None

    class cls2(BaseModel):
        three: int = 3
        four: cls1 = Field(None, title="TestMe")

    print()
    pprint(cls2.schema())
```

I get the following result;

```
{'definitions': {'cls1': {'properties': {'one': {'title': 'One',
                                                 'type': 'string'},
                                         'two': {'title': 'Two',
                                                 'type': 'string'}},
                          'required': ['one'],
                          'title': 'cls1',
                          'type': 'object'}},
 'properties': {'four': {'allOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/cls1'}],
                         'title': 'TestMe'},
                'three': {'default': 3, 'title': 'Three', 'type': 'integer'}},
 'title': 'cls2',
 'type': 'object'}
```

Note that cls1 is still presented as a definition and referenced. I want the value to be nested, not referenced. According to the documentation, I would expect that to occur when modifying the title of the Field object.

**Q:** It not via the approach above, How do I force Pydantic to nest a model when creating a json-schema instead of calling by reference?

[Update]
I added this question as an issue on github, thinking it might be a bug;  https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/3627

[Update]
funnydman was kind enough to point me to an existing issue. If you scroll to the very bottom, you will find a post-processing solution. I'm still left with the confusion that the documentation seems to imply the ability to do what I am asking? https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/889

Comment: The same question has been asked already: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/889

Comment: thank you, and respectfully, @funnydman, The issue pointed to claims that there is no native solution, but the documentation that I reference above at least seems to propose the possibility. It would still be valuable, I believe, to understand if the documentation is incorrect, my understanding is incorrect, or it has been an added feature?

Comment: Your issue has been closed with the reference to the issue I had pointed before.

Comment: But I could agree, that solution does not answer the question